# Bootstrap carousel without using left class (or scoping it)

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I use a few classes for placing elements on the page in a specific manor.  One of them happens to be the following

```
.left {
  float: left;
}
```

While using the carousel I noticed that the image that was supposed to slide left and out, just disappeared instead.  I then noticed that as it was supposed to slide out it got the class "left".

Connecting these two, I removed my own left class temporarily and saw it fixed the problem.  My problem remains that I use this left class a lot and would really like to keep it.

Is there a way to fix this while keeping my class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I was typing the question I figured out some of the structure that it uses, so by simply using the below code, it should set it back:

```
.carousel-inner .left {
  float:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can override bootstrap's `left` class. Just add in your class:

```
float: none !important;
```